# JSON.stringify converts object's property names into strings

Tags: javascript, json

I have an object like this.

```
var obj = {
    name: "foo",
    age: 23
};

for (i in obj) {
    if (obj[i] == "foo") {
    obj[i] = "bob";
  }
}
```

After manipulating the object
when using `JSON.stringify(obj)` i getting the output like this.

```
{"name":"bob","age":23}
```

But i don't need the objects property as string how to convert into objects property name. so i need the ouput like this `{name:"bob",age:23}`. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: What's wrong in having properties as string?

Comment: That's the json format bro.

Comment: I know there is no problem in having properties as string. but i need the output format to be like i asked in the question

Comment: Why don't you just not stringify the object??

Comment: if you don't need to stringify the object why would you convert it to JSON in the first place?

Comment: @htoniv — For `JavaScript` object, keys are always `strings`.. always....

Comment: I getting the ouput value in browser console. so i need the keys value not in string. using JSON.stringify only i get the complete json to copy

Comment: JSON.parse('{"name":"bob","age":23}')

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Comment: @connexo i know JSON.parse converts keys string value. but how can i copy the entire value. it is a huge amount of json.

Comment: where do you need the properties without quotes?

Comment: in browser console.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like the right output.

In the wiki the example looks the same [WIKI JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#edit)

In JS that shouldnt be a problem at all.

Pls look at this to parse your JSON string back to an object [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Maybe it would be smarter to tell us why you need to remove the double qoutes from the key. Probably JSON is not the problem, I would look at the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do this, as `{"name":"bob","age":23}` is valid JSON. But if you really want to remove the quotes around the keys:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
var keyVals = json.substr(1,json.length-2).split(/,/g);

var output = "{";
keyVals.forEach(function(keyVal) {
   var parts = keyVal.split(":");
   output += parts[0].replace(/"/g, "");
   output += ":";
   output += parts[1];
   output += ",";
});

output = output.substr(0, output.length - 1);

output += "}";
```

Answer (score 1):

As Anirudha said. if you want to remove the double quote of keys, you need regular expression. As fllows:

```
JSON.stringify(obj).replace(/"([^"]*)":/g, '$1:')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can use the regular expression to solve this problem

```
console.log(JSON.stringify({"name":"bob","age":23}).replace(/\"([^(\")"]+)\":/g,"$1:"))
```

Comment: Sorry to answer my own question. but without using regExp i need the solution

Comment: I know JSON.stringify converts key values in to string. but i dont need the output like this. please understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing an object with JSON.stringify(obj) does not read just your properties values, but also your properties names in order to transform an object into a JSON string ( example syntax style look in package.json where bouth properties and values have parenthases ). Your object properties become strings because the object is stringified, so if you dont want properties to be strings don use JSON.stringify() on the object.